# How to use flexslider in two jquery ui tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am trying to use flexslider in two ui tabs. In first tab it is loading correctly . But in second tabs it is loading the last image. But If i click the outside of the browser or minimize the browser then second tab load the first image. Here is code

```
<div id="tabs-1">
                        <div class="flexslider " >
                            <ul class="slides">
                                <li data-thumb="images/1_thumb.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/1.jpg ">

                                </li>
                                <li data-thumb="images/2_thumb.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/2.jpg">

                                <li data-thumb="images/3_thumb.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/3.jpg">

                                </li>
                                <li data-thumb="images/4.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/4.jpg">

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tabs-2">
                        <div class="flexslider" id="slider2" >
                            <ul class="slides">
                                <li data-thumb="images/1_thumb.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/1.jpg ">

                                </li>
                                <li data-thumb="images/2_thumb.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/2.jpg">

                                <li data-thumb="images/3_thumb.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/3.jpg">

                                </li>
                                <li data-thumb="images/4.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/4.jpg">

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>


                    </div>
```

script:

```
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  create: function( e, ui ) {
    ui.panel.find( ".flexslider" ).flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: "thumbnails",
       // animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false

    });
},
beforeActivate: function( e, ui ) {
    ui.oldPanel.find( ".flexslider" ).flexslider( "destroy" );
    ui.newPanel.find( ".flexslider" ).flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: "thumbnails",
        //animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false

    });
}
});
```

This is site link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/168659703/zaarly_v2/page1.html .When i set

```
  animationLoop: false
```

then works perfectly. Please tell me where is the problem .

Comment: Try uploading ur js on top of the page not at the end

Comment: for initializing flexslider in jquery try using id selector and not the class selector, give both the sliders a different id and then try to do this

Answer (score 0):

> Any component that requires some dimensional computations for its initialization won't work in a hidden tab, because the tab panel is itself hidden via display: none; so that any elements within it will not report its actual height and width. (0 in most browsers)

Here is your [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/hWLcB/)

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
 beforeActivate: function( e, ui ) {
     if(ui.oldTab.length>0){
        ui.oldTab.find( ".flexslider" ).flexslider( "destroy" );
     }
 },
 show: function(e,ui){
    $(ui.panel).find( ".flexslider" ).flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: "thumbnails",
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false
    });
 }
});
```

I'm deleting the slider in "beforeActivate" and initializing the next tab slider in "show". Because by then the new Tab is activated and visible.